# Need to search substring or any matching string using auto complete entered in the textbox using C#

Tags: c#, search, combobox, textbox

I am trying to make a search tool but my textbox auto complete cannot search for substring,it only shows result for auto complete if the match is equivalent.

I have tried the autocomplete textbox and auto complete combo box,I need a search where if user puts in ab all string containing the substring ab should pop up.

already tried auto complete mode both text box and combo box.

```
textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
AutoCompleteStringCollection col = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
col.Add("Foo");
col.Add("Bar");
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col;
```

This works only when I search "F" or "B" but not with the substring "oo" or "ar".

Comment: WinForms autocomplete can only search from the begining. You need to implement your own autocomplete.

Comment: can you give me any examples ?

Comment: u can refer this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694720/combobox-autocomplete-on-substring

Comment: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43254621/customize-textbox-autocomplete), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694720/combobox-autocomplete-on-substring), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11780558/c-sharp-winforms-combobox-dynamic-autocomplete), [four](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515561/how-can-i-dynamically-change-auto-complete-entries-in-a-c-sharp-combobox-or-text), [five](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8762982/c-sharp-create-custom-autocomplete-textbox), should I proceed?

Answer (score -1):

```
textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
AutoCompleteStringCollection col = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
col.Add("Foo");
col.Add("Bar");
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = col;
```

Keep coding!